# Multiline string with added text from variables

Tags: c#

I am aware this will work:

```
string multiline_text = @"this is a multiline text
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3";
```

How can I make the following work:

```
string a1 = " line number one";
string a2 = " line number two";
string a3 = " line number three";

string multiline_text = @"this is a multiline text
this is " + a1 + " 
this is " + a2 + " 
this is " + a3 + ";
```

Is it possible without splitting the string into several substring, one for each line?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

One option is to use string formatting instead. Before C# 6:

```
string pattern = @"this is a multiline text
this is {0}
this is {1}
this is {2}";

string result = string.Format(pattern, a1, a2, a3);
```

With C# 6, you can use an interpolated verbatim string literal:

```
string pattern = $@"this is a multiline text
this is {a1}
this is {a2}
this is {a3}";
```

Note that `$@` has to be exactly that - if you try to use `@$`, it won't compile.

Comment: @Jodrell An easy answer for Jon Skeet would be a complete rewrite of the C# language itself. This answer here is as simple as breathing for Jon :)

Comment: Downvoted since this answer is out of date now that C# supports template strings.

Comment: @MicahZoltu: Edited. (Not that the earlier code would have stopped working in C# 6 or anything...)

Comment: Upvoted.  :)  The reason for the downvote wasn't because this answer was wrong, it was because another answer was now "better" IMO and I wanted the "better" answer to start bubbling up to the top.  (I recognize that better is subjective here).  Anyway, now that this answer has C# 6 interpolated strings I'm a fan.

Comment: @MicahZoltu: You can of course vote how you want, but I would suggest only downvoting answers which are (in the terms of the tooltip) "not useful". Downvoting one answer to effectively make an upvote twice as useful isn't a good strategy, IMO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't know that there were best practices for up/down voting.  I always assumed that the voting was intended simply to move content up or down but it sounds like downvoting is intended to reduce spam and abuse only and upvoting is the sole mechanism for moving content around.

Comment: @MicahZoltu: It's not meant to be about "moving" so much as saying "I think this answer is good." For example, if I see a question with three good answers, I'll happily upvote *all* of them... nothing is moved at all, but all the answers engender that bit more confidence to anyone reading them in the future.

Comment: What if i want to add a variable inside a { } as part of the text ? this {{a1}} does not work ?

Comment: @ATHER: You'd use `{{{a}}}`. The `{{` and `}}` are escaped braces, then the `{a}` in the midle is the value of `a`.

Answer (score 8):

Although `string.Format` is better practice, to do what you're trying to achieve, just add the extra `@`s at the end of each line:

```
string multiline_text = @"this is a multiline text
this is " + a1 + @" 
this is " + a2 + @" 
this is " + a3 + @"";
```

You were also missing a last `"` before the ending semi colon.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually the simplest and most efficient answer, while Jon Skeet's is the most elegant.

Answer (score 5):

You can gain readability like this from the `StringBuilder` class:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("this is a multiline");
sb.AppendLine("this is " + a1); // etc

var result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: And it's worse performance-wise. By default the compiler will do `constant folding` on OP's provided `string`. `StringBuilder`s are only better when loops are involved.

Comment: Notice the term "readability" in my answer. Considering how the question was asked, I figured this was the deal here.

Comment: For inserting variables StringBuilder.AppendFormat is worth a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

With C# 6 (Visual Studio 2015), you can write:

```
string multiline_text = $@"this is a multiline text
this is {a1}
this is {a2}
this is {a3}";
```

String.Format will be used by compiler (like in Jons answer), but it's easier to read.

Comment: I guess this has more to do with C# version instead of visual studio version

Answer (score 0):

For some reason c# doesn't support multi-line text like that.  the closest you'll get is:

```
string a1 = " line number one";
string a2 = " line number two";
string a3 = " line number three";

string multiline_text = @"this is a multiline text" +
"this is " + a1 +
"this is " + a2 +
"this is " + a3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that goes along the lines of Jon Skeet's answer is this:

```
string result = string.Format(
    "this is a multiline text{0}this is {1}{0}this is {2}{0}this is {3}",
    Environment.NewLine, a1, a2, a3);
```

and so basically you're inserting a new line where you want one with `{0}`. It makes the string a little more abstract because of that, but the benefit of this solution is that it's fully encapsulated within the `string.Format` method. It's probably not all that relevant -but worth mentioning.

Comment: Except that `"this is NOT a multiline text...`

Comment: @enb081, what? I don't follow your comment?

Comment: @enb081, ***you're actually wrong.*** The `Environment.NewLine` string constant is inserted at every `{0}` and therefore creates a multiline string out of one single line of text.

Comment: I want the text outside the `{0}`, `{1}` and `{2}` to be multiline too.

Comment: @enb081, this would produce a string like this `this is a multiline text\r\nthis is "value of a1"\r\nthis is "value of a2"\r\nthis is "value of a3"` where every `\r\n` is in fact a new line, just like what you're inserting into the string with the IDE. It produces the same string -but with a single `string.Format` command. How about you plug it in and check it out??

Comment: You are not understanding, the text after replacing the value of `{3}` continues in many other lines. I tried it, that's why i'm commenting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28828/discussion-between-michael-perrenoud-and-enb081)

Answer (score 0):

For fun, you can also use an array join technique to get something readable and control indenting. Sometimes the multi-line template forcing you to fully left align is unsightly...

```cs
string a1 = "London", a2 = "France", a3 = "someone's underpants";

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new[] {
    $"this is {a1}", // interpolated strings look nice
    "this is " + a2, // you can concat if you can't interpolate
    $"this is {a3}"  // these in-line comments can be nice too
});
```

if you must format, wrap the join for a tidy result instead of individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since C# 11 and .NET 7 [raw string literals](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#raw-string-literals) are available which support [interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```cs
string a1 = " line number one";
string a2 = " line number two";
string a3 = " line number three";

string multiline_text = $"""
this is a multiline text
this is {a1} 
this is {a2}
this is {a3}
""";
```